# Alignment of nested databinding with ItemsControl in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have the following datatemplate:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel x:Name="GroupStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=GroupName}">
                         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
                               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                         <StackPanel x:Name="BtnStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                               <Button Content="{Binding Path=LabelString}"
                                                                Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}"/>
                                          </StackPanel>
                                     </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           </ItemsControl>
                      </GroupBox>
                 </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This includes some ButtonGroups and Buttons which are in this Group.

The class Group includes a string-property "GroupName" and an ObservableCollection-property "Buttons". The allocation of buttons and groups is working correctly.

So here is my problem: I want to have this buttongroups in a **ribbontab** in the **dockpanel**. But the alignment or the orientation is false, so the buttons are one below the other and not *next to each other*.
Has anyone an idea what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you're using a `Stackpanel` with horizontal orientation, which is the right idea, but the `Stackpanel` is in the wrong place (the `ItemTemplate`). The `ItemTemplate`  is applied to every item in an `ItemsControl`, which means that your XAML represents a collection of buttons where each is surrounded by its very own `StackPanel`.

To have the desired effect, you instead need to specify the `Stackpanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`.

Try changing your inner clause to:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Button Content="{Binding Path=LabelString}" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel x:Name="BtnStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>  
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**

If you want both groups and buttons to display horizontally, you can do the same thing to both:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>         
       <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=GroupName}">
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                 <Button Content="{Binding Path=LabelString}" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
             <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel x:Name="BtnStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>  
             <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          </ItemsControl>
        </GroupBox>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel x:Name="GroupStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: thanks. that looks good. so now the buttons are next to each other but the groups are still below to each other.

Comment: Yep - you can do a similar thing with the groups if you need to :)

Comment: yes i did so but now i get a Exception: "The Children collection of "panel", which is used as "ItemsPanel" for "ItemsControl" can not be explicitly changed."

Comment: I've edited my example to do this - maybe check that you've got the same? I didn't post this originally as I thought it would be a bit much all at once and the syntax is clearer with just the one

Comment: thanks a lot. now it works. i think i always did it exactly the different way :)