# Databinding on multiple levels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Last question of the day.

I am new to MVVM modelling and have achieved quite a bit with my understanding of it but I would need guidance on something before I screw my entire project up by fiddling around.

I have created a model named Person which has the below:

```
- General info like: ID, FirstName, LastName, FullName, Nationality etc.
- A list of old jobs
- Each job (a separate model) within the old jobs list has data as well such as YearStarted, YearEnded, Occupation, Company etc.
```

So my model looks like this:

```
- Person:
     - ID
     - Name
     - Nationality
     - Jobs:
          - Job1:
               - Occupation
               - Started
               - Ended
               - Salary
               - Duties:
                    - Duties 1
                    - Duties 2
          - Job2:
               - Occupation
               - Started
               - Ended
               - Salary
               - Duties:
                    - Duties 1
                    - Duties 2
                    - Duties 3
```

In my view, the list of People shows perfectly. When I click on one of the people, I am opening a new WPF page with their own control. I have set up a constructor called ClickedPerson that retrieves the Person Model data of the person clicked. Works perfectly and I can show the 1st level data such as the person's Name by Binding as such: {Binding Path=ClickedPerson.Name}

My question is: how can I have an ItemsControl that would show the level 2 and level 3 of that person's data? Meaning, if I were to implement an ItemsControl where there would be a stackpanel with 1 new UserControl (for instance) for each OldJob in the person's life and then have that UserControl's child controls reflect that old job's specific data like the Occupation or Salary in textboxes => How can I write the binding part in XAML?

Don't worry about the UI, I can deal with that, it is merely the Binding part that I am unsure of.

Let me know if I explained it like a blind gorilla ...

UPDATE:
So with what you guys are saying, I have written the below simple UI binding but it is not showing anything. What am i doing wrong?

```
                <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClickedPerson}">
                    <!-- List of OldJobs teamplate -->
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Duties}">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding JobNumber}" />

                            <!-- Job template -->
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Occupation}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

UPDATE 2:
I'm not getting this am I??

I have written this in my ViewModel and View based on what I have read and what you guys have said... Thought it would work but shows nothing in my Treeview:

```
private Person _clickedPerson;
public CollectionViewSource ClickedPersonJobs { get; set; }

public Person ClickedPerson
        {
            get { return _clickedPerson; }
            set
            {
                _ clickedPerson = value;
                ClickedPersonJobs = new CollectionViewSource();
                ClickedPersonJobs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("JobNumber", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                ClickedPersonJobs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("JobNumber"));
                ClickedPersonJobs.Source = _ clickedPerson.OldJobs;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ClickedPerson);
            }
        }
```

and in my View XAML file:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClickedPersonJobs }"
                                  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">

                            <!-- Job teamplate -->
                            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Duties}">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Occupation}" />

                                    <!-- Duties template -->
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                        </TreeView>
```

Comment: I think this should work assuming `ClickedPerson` is a collection of your `Person` model

Comment: I think you need to specify the data type for the template

Comment: I hope you have set the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TreeView of WPF. `HierarchialDataTemplate` will help you here.

for a simple exmaple see MSDN[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:League}"
                            ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Divisions}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:Division}"
                            ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Team}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

This shows you a 3 level hierarchy.

```
League
    Division
       Team
```

The key is to use the ItemsSource of HierarchicalDataTemplate and providing the correct DataTemplate for each.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an MVVM issue, but a `Binding` path syntax issue. As such, you might want to view the [Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) page at MSDN.

From the linked page:

> When the source is a collection view, the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.

Basically, this means that you can use the following `Binding` to display the `Occupation` of the selected `Job` from the selected `Person`:

```
{Binding PersonCollection/JobCollection/Occupation}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example where i have something like you, but with Buttongroups and Buttons (instead of your Jobs and Job1, Job2,... So in my ViewModel i have a property of an  `ObservableCollection<ButtonGroups> Groups`. My ButtonGroups-Model has a string GroupName and an ObservableCollection with Buttons where I declare the LabelString and the ButtonCommand.

My ItemsControl looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Groups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>         
   <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=GroupName}">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
             <Button Content="{Binding Path=LabelString}" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel x:Name="BtnStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>  
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
 </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <StackPanel x:Name="GroupStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

It gives me a row of Buttons which i have defined. So I have 1 ItemsControl for each Button. You can modify your ItemsControl to have your Jobs and the properties of each job you want to show.

Here is my question, where i got that: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357047/alignment-of-nested-databinding-with-itemscontrol-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `DataGrid` here which will take the List of `Person` as its `ItemsSource`. Once you do that, each DataGridRow will have object of `Person` as its `DataContext`. Now you can have columns in `DataGrid` bound to properties of `Person`.

Next you can define the `RowDetailsTemplate` to show the hierarycal data. You can set the rowtemplate to have `DataGrid` again to show the jobs in it. As `DataContext` for this datagrid will also be Person object you can bind to JobList inside person to populate the data it in. Similary you can have multiple hierarchies.

```
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Occupation}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Started}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Salary}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

Thanks